# softkeyboard moves all layout up

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

When AlertDialog with EditText is showing, softkeyboard moves up layout of activity. This happens when i use trackball and all subsequent attempts after using trackball. when i call dialog in touch mode - softkeyboard overlay on my layout. what i can do to always overlay may layout with soft keyboard?

Comment: Try this android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" I'm not sure but hope this works.

Answer (score 5):

Put `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` on your `Activity` on the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"  
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your layout inside a scrollview.

Answer (score 2):

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"